# How to copy Google sheet Table to Google doc with same text color and formatting?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I am trying to import table from google sheet to Google doc using google apps script. So far I have been able to import data table to doc with partial formatting. The `issue` is Font Style and text color is not preserved when table is imported to google doc.

Here is the code:

```
function appendTable() {
  
  // Replace these values with your Sheet ID, Document ID, and Sheet Name
  
  let ssId = '<Spreadsheet Id>' // REPLACE
  let docId = '<Google doc Id>' // REPLACE
  let sheetName = '<Sheet Name>' // REPLACE
  
  // Sheet
  let range = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName(sheetName).getDataRange()
  let values = range.getValues();
  let backgroundColors = range.getBackgrounds();
  let styles = range.getTextStyles();
  
  
 // Document
  let body = DocumentApp.openById(docId).getBody();
  let table = body.appendTable(values);
 
  for (let i=0; i<table.getNumRows(); i++) {
    for (let j=0; j<table.getRow(i).getNumCells(); j++) {
      
      let docStyles = {};
      
      docStyles[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR] = backgroundColors[i][j];
      docStyles[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = styles[i][j].getFontSize();
      docStyles[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = styles[i][j].isBold();
     // docStyles[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = colors[i][j];
      
      table.getRow(i).getCell(j).setAttributes(docStyles);
    }
  }
}
```

When script runs, it imports the following table from the sheet:

[image: Sheet Table]

But the imported table in Google doc lose its formatting and looks like this:

[image: Doc Table]

Can you please guide me on what am I missing here, why the Font style of the table in Google docs and the text color not the same as the sheet table? Here is the

> [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IZtt1NIq4eBRr9z5X7ywJqI2GqUWq4Rbppxdh5b-W5I/edit?usp=sharing)

to the sample sheet. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I saw your showing images, I thought that it is required to include `DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR` in `docStyles`. So, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
 let docStyles = {};
 
 docStyles[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR] = backgroundColors[i][j];
 docStyles[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = styles[i][j].getFontSize();
 docStyles[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = styles[i][j].isBold();
// docStyles[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = colors[i][j];
 
 table.getRow(i).getCell(j).setAttributes(docStyles);
```

#### To:

```
let docStyles = {};
docStyles[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR] = backgroundColors[i][j];
docStyles[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = styles[i][j].getFontSize();
docStyles[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = styles[i][j].isBold();
docStyles[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = styles[i][j].getForegroundColorObject().asRgbColor().asHexString(); // Added
table.getRow(i).getCell(j).setAttributes(docStyles);
```

#### Reference:

- [getForegroundColorObject()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-style#getforegroundcolorobject)

Comment: @Sohaib435 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. In this modification, in order to retrieve the font color of the cell value, `getForegroundColorObject()` is used. In the current stage, it seems that `getForegroundColor()` can be still used. But, this method is deprecated. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-style#getForegroundColor()) So, in the current stage, please use `getForegroundColorObject()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function appendTable() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ssid")
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const rg = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn())
  const vs = rg.getValues();
  const bs = rg.getBackgrounds();
  const fws = rg.getFontWeights();
  const fss = rg.getFontSizes();
  const sts = rg.getTextStyles();
  const d = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const b = d.getBody();
  const tbl = b.appendTable(vs);
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    r.forEach((c,j) => {
      let sty = {};
      sty[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR] = bs[i][j];
      sty[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = fss[i][j];
      sty[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = (fws[i][j] == 'bold') ? true: false;
      sty[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = sts[i][j].getForegroundColorObject().asRgbColor().asHexString();
      tbl.getRow(i).getCell(j).setAttributes(sty);
    });
  });
}
```

Sheet0:

[image]

Doc:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Cooper, I would try that, but I think it is also missing the text color attribute as Tanaike proposed in his answer