# Copy table from Google Sheets into Google Docs while keeping formatting using Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I am trying to copy a table from sheets to docs but in doing so it was not keeping the format.

I did end up finding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73809126/how-to-copy-google-sheet-table-to-google-doc-with-same-text-color-and-formatting) which allowed me to keep formatting but only if the entire cell had that formatting whereas my table looks more like this

[image]

Is there any way to do this and keep all that formatting?

Comment: When you say all formatting, that makes it a big task.  Font, font size, font style, foreground color, background color, alignment, etc. etc.

Comment: Not to mention cell height and width, which would almost have to be done cell by cell.

Comment: I guess I'm more focused on the basic Bold, Italics, underline, etc.. The font itself and the cells width and height aren't as important to transfer between

Comment: Even that is not that easy.  Font styling is done using Rich Text which has various properties to properly display.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of at least duplicating the Rich Text from Spreadsheet to Document.  You can see how many parameter need to be checked to duplicate the text format.

I've provided a few links to get you started if you need any other attributes.

I started with this spreadsheet.

[image]

And ended up with this document.

[image]

**Code.gs**

```
function copyTable() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Test2");
    let richText = sheet.getDataRange().getRichTextValues();
    let doc = DocumentApp.create("Test2");
    let body = doc.getBody()
    let table = body.appendTable();

    richText.forEach( row => {
        let tableRow = table.appendTableRow();
        row.forEach( cell => {
            let tableCell = tableRow.appendTableCell();
            tableCell.setText( cell.getText() );
            let text = tableCell.editAsText();
            let runs = cell.getRuns();
            runs.forEach( run => {
                let start = run.getStartIndex();
                let end = run.getEndIndex()-1;
                if( start === end ) return;
                let textStyle = run.getTextStyle(start,end);
                let fontFamily = textStyle.getFontFamily();
                let fontSize = textStyle.getFontSize();
                let fontColor = textStyle.getForegroundColorObject().asRgbColor().asHexString();
                let bold = textStyle.isBold();
                let italic = textStyle.isItalic();
                let strikeThrough = textStyle.isStrikethrough();
                let underLine = textStyle.isUnderline();
                text.setFontFamily(start,end,fontFamily);
                text.setFontSize(start,end,fontSize);
                text.setForegroundColor(start,end,fontColor);
                if( bold ) {
                  text.setBold(start,end,bold);
                }
                else if( italic ) {
                  text.setItalic(start,end,italic)
                }
                if( strikeThrough ) {
                  text.setStrikethrough(start,end,strikeThrough)
                }
                else if( underLine ) {
                  text.setUnderline(start,end,underLine )
                }
              }
            );
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error in copyTable: "+err);
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- [Range.getRichTextValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getRichTextValues())
- [RichTextValue.getRuns()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value#getRuns())
- [TableCell.editAsText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-cell#editAsText())